# Why does the click function not work after I change the class of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of buttons(previous & next) that the user clicks.

```
<a id="prev_btn" class="prev_1" href="#">Previous</a>
<a id="next_btn" class="next_1" href="#">Next</a>
```

When the user clicks on the next button(.next_1), it changes the class name of the button to next_2 and changes the the previous button(.prev_1) to prev_2. Once the class name is changed, the click function that is set for prev_2 doesn't work.

```
$('.next_1').click(function() {
  $('#next_btn').removeClass('next_1').addClass('next_2');
  $('#prev_btn').removeClass('prev_1 inactive').addClass('prev_2');
});

$('.prev_2').click(function() {
  alert('this works');
});
```

Why does the click function not work after I change the class using jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the bindings are defined at load.  If you want them to work dynamically, bind teh click's via LIVE.

```
$('.prev_2').live('click', function() {
       alert('hi!');
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much! The only thing that needs to be added is the beginning single quote for the selector.

Comment: Glad to help, an sorry about the typo.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are confused about the time of evaluation here; `$('.prev_2')` gets all elements that currently have a class of 'prev_2', and applies a given action to them; it is not a declaration that stays in effect no matter which elements are added to or removed from this class.

If you want a handler that is based on class, you can register an onclick handler at the document level, and test the class of the event target and dispatch accordingly. However, it is cleaner just to register a click function with a specific button and, within that handler, test the class of the button before acting.

Answer (score 2):

When `$('.prev_2').click(...)` is executed, the "previous" button does not have the prev_2 class, so it is not assigned the click handler, only thingas which *currently* have that calss when the `.click` method is *called* will have that handler bound.

You want to look at the `.live` jquery function to achive what you are looking for